# Why characteristic functions of regular domains are not in $W^{1,p}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain with $\partial E\in C^1$.

I don't know how to prove that its characteristic function $\chi_E$ is NOT in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R^n})$.

It's obvious that $\chi_E$ is in $L^p$ and that:

$\langle\nabla T_{\chi_E},X\rangle=-\int_E \text{div}( X) \ dx$,

but i don't know how to continue.

Comment: By limited domain do you perhaps mean a bounded domain?

Comment: Hint: Clearly indicator functions aren’t continuous, so it’s unlikely they’ll be weakly differentiable. Can you prove this rigorously? (think about what being in $W^{1,p}$ tells you about smoothness)

Comment: Forget about "$C^1$ domains" a minute and show rigorously that $ \chi_{[0,1]} $ is not $ W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}) $.  What you learn from that example will quickly tell you what you need to know for the general case in question.

Comment: I see, one can show the general case likewise to the one dimensional case using the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations